# How to create a video with audio and video from frames and a vector

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video

I am trying to create video clips merged with audio on python.
I have a list of frames and a desired frame rate for the video and a for the audio I have a numpy vector with known sampling rate.
I was able to create video files using opencv however I couldn't find a way to combine it with the audio.
So the question is, is there a way to create a video file from a list of numpy matricides representing frames of video and an a numpy array representing the audio?

I looking into doing this with ffmpeg, however, with this method, I need to save the files first, and merge both files afterwards, this takes time to save and load

## load the audio file

```
audio_name='Metallica - Master Of Puppets S&M [HQ].mp3'
x, sr = librosa.load(audio_name) 
ipd.Audio(x, rate=sr)
```

## Load the viedo

```
import cv2

video_name = 'vid_sample.avi'
new_video_name='new_'+video_name
vidcap = cv2.VideoCapture(video_name)
success,image = vidcap.read()
count = 0
success = True
frame_list=[]

while success:
    #cv2.imshow('image',image) #Display the video
    frame_list.append(image)
    if cv2.waitKey(10) == 27:                     # exit if Escape is hit
        vidcap.release() 
        cv2.destroyAllWindows() 
        break
    success,image = vidcap.read()
    count += 1
# Release all space and windows once done 
    vidcap.release() 
    cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

## Do some manipulations to the video and save frame to "new_list"(not showen)

new_list contains frames just like frame_list

## Create a new video

```
height,width,layers=new_list[1].shape
video=cv2.VideoWriter(new_video_name,cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*'DIVX'),fps (width,height))
for i in range(len(new_list)):
    video.write(new_list[i])
video.release()
```

Comment: opencv is for computer vision. Have a look at media libraries like ffmpeg etc.

Comment: thank you @Micka , I know this, I am asking if there is a library that with which I can grab a list of frames, a vector of audio and combine them. ffmpeg does allow you to merge audio and video file but to use it, i will have to first save the video that i created with opencv, then load the video along with the audio file (which i already loaded but i'll need to load it again) and only then combine the two.

Comment: libAV is the library used by ffmpeg, which you can use from your code, instead of using the ffmpeg executable

Comment: so in short, i will have to make the video, save it then load it with ffmpeg along with the audio file to merge them? is there no way around it? is there an option to make the video out of frames and raw audio vector?

Is it possible to get a "steam" of audio from raw audio signal and a "stream" of video from raw video frames to feed to ffmpeg?

Comment: try libAV......

Comment: sorry, you are using python... probably not possible there, but I am not an expert in the python world. Good luck.